# Kali Linux Version doesn't match ISO (?)

Tags: kali-linux

I downloaded "Kali 2018.3" from kali.org, and booted my thumbdrive from it. As of time of writing, this is the latest version I see on the official site.

However, when I run "uname -r" I see "4.17.0-kali1-amd64" This seems to me they don't match.

When I look for mac drivers, they are all for version 4.18 (but I thought I had the latest). What am I missing?

Comment: From [this page](https://www.kali.org/releases/kali-linux-2018-3-release/) it seems that the correct command is `# grep VERSION /etc/os-release`. If not, you could upgrade `apt update && apt -y full-upgrade`. However, and **before** any of that, did you [check the sha256sum](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) of the iso? For security, you must.

Answer (score 6):

The Linux kernel is just one piece of software that makes up Kali Linux. The version of Kali as a whole is 2018.3, and the version of the kernel is 4.17.0-kali1-amd64. There's no conflict or mismatch.